# Uploading my site to github without uploading previously deleted files

Tags: git, github

I've figured out how to upload the files to github but the site I copied up initially included a bunch of files and folders I no longer want.  (it was my first attempt at using github).  Obviously I want a clean version of the site up on github for my master copy, so I've gone and cleaned up the site on my local machine (reorganized a bit and deleted old stuff), thinking all I have to do is delete the repository on github and start over.

Unfortunately it seems no matter what I do, these unwanted files and folders keep getting copied up, even though I've deleted them from both my local machine and my github repository.

This is what I tried.

1. On my local machine I deleted a bunch of files and folders I no longer want and also restructured the folders a bit.
2. On the github site I go into settings for my respository and delete the repository.
3. Using the github client on Windows I right click on my repository and choose "Open in Git Shell".
4. In Git Shell I type "git push" thinking it will push up only the files and folders that exist on my local machine.  I thought wrong.

For some reason it keeps copying up all the old files and folders that have long since been deleted.  Where is it getting these files from and how can I stop it from doing this?

Comment: do you update your `.gitignore` file in your local branch with that deleted files

Comment: Have you deleted the files only from your working copy or did you also commit the deletions?

Comment: I did not do a commit.  I guess that's an important step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to commit above and your question i think answer will be

`git add --all`

Then add commit

`git commit -m 'deleted files'`

Then push to github

`git push origin`

Comment: What does "origin" refer to in your answer?

Comment: default name for remote branch

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried it all again, but this time with a commit before the push and it worked.  The deleted files did not come back.